# rails rescue function

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

i have a products controller on my site and what i decided to do is use the `rescue` command in rails so that people can't enter products/500 and get the rails error message for a product that doesn't exist. here's what my code looks like

```
def show
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @title = @product.name
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'No such product'
end
```

but then i saw some other places where people use `begin` `rescue` and `else`. is the code below a better practice. it works both ways, but i would like to know what the difference is between these two codes

```
def show
  begin
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path, :notice => 'No such product'
  else
    @title = @product.name
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One isolates the thing that causes the exception, one doesn't.

Not really sure if one is a "better practice" or not; I like to keep "things that can go horribly wrong" isolated, but I find begin/rescue/else unwieldy when reading, because I have to "skip ahead" to see what happens if there *isn't* an exception. Not a lot, but meh.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you'd want to use the begin/rescue/else (and optional ensure) is if you're going to do something else afterwards.  In your case, the first of your examples is preferable.  It groups the "happy case" logic together, which is most of what you will likely want to focus on, but still leaves it clear what will happen if there is a failure.